# How do I flash a modem for CyanogenMod / CM10.2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have already flashed the latest nightly (as of this time) and the corresponding gapps for my Samsung Galaxy S4 via CWM. But when I checked the Phone settings (About Phone), Baseband version is Unknown.

I have already tried flashing I9505XXUEMJ7_MODEM.tar via Odin (as Phone), but the Baseband is still Unknown.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue (old CWM):

- Upgraded CWM from 6.0.3.2 to 6.0.4.4 using ROM Manager.
- Rebooted to Recovery Mode
- Wipe Data / Factory Reset
- Wipe Cache Partition
- Wipe Dalvik Cache
- Flash CM zip (two times)
- Flash GAPPS
- Reboot phone (boot animation now showed; this was just black before)

After the phone booted, (and the usual wizard),
I noticed the Baseband was no longer Unknown,
but listed my previously-flashed modem.

I rebooted phone into Download mode and flashed a different modem (for my region).

Phone working normally now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't solve your problem of flashing a Modem via Odin, but have you had a look at the Collection of CWM modems, e.g. here
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=47234771&postcount=1220&nocache=1&z=1674485336989164

There is this hint:

> Originally Posted by lambstone
>   Ok it worked.
>   If anyone else is having issues with the baseband not changing, do this.

```
Use Odin v3.04
Untick Autoreboot
Flash modem
Reboot once again into Download Mode using (Vol Down plus Home button combi)
Flash Modem once more
Once done,unplug then reboot device manually.
If this doesn't work, try repeating the flash process again while rebooting manually and with auto-reboot option turned off.
```

Comment: Yes, I know that list. There are no CWM-flashable modems for the S4. I flashed one via Odin, but it still didn't show up on my phone settings. Still Unknown.

Comment: have you tried flashing via "Mobile ODIN" ? Hint:  rename tar.md5 to .tar and open it as MODEM